# Error SQL7008 while running an Update and/or Delete from a StoredProcedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I'm using a DB2 database.
I understand this error occurs when the table i am trying to update is not being journalled, and the update is being run within a transaction. 
I can't modify the entire database, but I can modify the table i am trying to update/delete from, and my StoredProcedure, so i'm looking for solution i could implement on my storedProcedure or on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Either journal the table, or turn off transactions at the

- Connection  (ex in Java)

  jdbc:as400://systemname;naming=sql;errors=full;transaction isolation=none;date format=iso
- Stored procedure

  SET OPTION COMMIT=*NONE;
- Statement

  UPDATE MYTABLE 
     SET MYFLD = 'Hi'
  WITH NC;

Comment: SET OPTION would apply to the whole procedure and would need to be done outside the DELETE statement.  If you just want to change the statement, with the `WITH NC`

Comment: When I try using `SET OPTION COMMIT=*NONE` on a Delete statement, it seems to skip the where, and it deletes everything, the same happens when i try to use `WITH NC` or `WITH NONE`